# How to only view business hours in a fullCalendar agenda view

Tags: fullcalendar

[image]

I want to show only business hours in a daily agenda view from 8:30 to 17:00,
like below:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you asking how to hide hours outside of business hours? If so, use the minTime and maxTime options:

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/minTime/

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/maxTime/

for instance, for a 9am - 5pm calendar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        ...
        minTime: "09:00:00",
        maxTime: "17:00:00",
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I use this also, but only minTime works for me, maxTime doesnt work, anyone knows what can be the problem?

Answer (score 10):

Addition to minTime and maxTime setting as @scottysmalls mentioned, adding `height: 'auto',` will help to remove blank area at the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

For FullCalendar v5, `minTime` and `maxTime` are both renamed. So, please use accordingly.

`minTime` is renamed to [slotMinTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMinTime)

`maxTime` is renamed to [slotMaxTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMaxTime)

For further reference:
[Upgrading from FullCalendar to V5](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4)

Comment: This work Perfect in version 6

Answer (score 1):

In version 5 the attributes have been renamed from:

`minTime` to `slotMinTime`

and

`maxTime` to `slotMaxTime`